# Нахождение наименьшего номера n члена последовательности (Pascal)

Tags: pascal, математика

Задача:

---

Написать программу для нахождения наименьшего номера n члена последовательности

```
(—1)<sup>n</sup> × ( (3<sup>n</sup> × (n)!) ÷ (2 × n — 1) )
```

при `n = 1, 2, 3, ...`

для которого разница между найденным и предыдущим членами последовательности не превышает заданной точности, а именно

```
| a<sub>n</sub> — a<sub>n — 1</sub> | < ε
```

при `ε = 0,000001 .`

---

Вот наброски. Дальше не совсем понимаю условие.

```
Program pr1;
var
  result, result_2,  factorial_1, factorial_2: real;
  j, x, i, n : integer;
Begin
    write('Введите n: ');
    read(n);
    for i:=2 to n do
        begin
            factorial_2 := 1;
            factorial_1 := 1;
            for j:=2 to i do
                factorial_1 := factorial_1 * j;
                result:=exp(ln(3)*i)*factorial_1;
            for x:=2 to (2*i-1) do
                factorial_2 := factorial_2 * x;
            if i mod 2 = 0 then
                result_2:= 1*(result/factorial_2)
            else
                result_2:= -1*(result/factorial_2);
            writeln(result_2);
        end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё решилось. Оставлю ответ может кому-то будет интересно.

```
Program hello_world;
function fact(n : integer) : real;
    var 
        f : real;
        i : integer;
    begin
        f := 1;
        if n>1 then 
            for i := 1 to n do f := f * i;
        fact := f;
    end;
var
    a : array [1..100] of real;
    i, n : integer;
begin
    const eps = 0.000001;
    a[1] := -3; 
    a[2] := 9*fact(2)/fact(3); 
    i := 2;
    writeln('1 член = ',a[1]); 
    writeln('2 член = ',a[2]);
    while ABS(a[i]-a[i-1]) >= eps do 
        begin
            inc(i);
            a[i] := power(-1,i)*power(3,i)*fact(i)/fact(2*i-1);
            writeln(i,' член = ',a[i]:0:10);
        end;
    write('Удовлетворяет условие - ',i);
end.
```